Reliability of the hadith, The Friday prayer in congregation is a necessary duty for every Muslim, with four exceptions; a slave, a woman
It says that Tariq b. Shihab had seen the Prophet (ﷺ) but not heard anything from him
On Sunnah.Com:

Narrated Tariq ibn Shihab:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The Friday prayer in congregation is a necessary duty for every Muslim, with four exceptions; a slave, a woman, a boy, and a sick person.
Abu Dawud said: Tariq b. Shihab had seen the Prophet (ﷺ) but not heard anything from him


The fact that Tariq ibn Shihab () had seen the Prophet (), but not heard anything from him can be regarded as an issue regarding the connection of the narrator chain. It means that Tariq ibn Shihab didn't mention the intermediate Sahabi () who had heard the words of the prophet () directly without intermediate.
So scholars tried to resolve or clarify the above issue and concluded:
As the narrator who has not cited his "teacher" was himself a sahabi () this report can be regarded as mursal of a sahabi which is a piece of acceptable evidence in fiqh matters.
Especially since the hadith was compiled following the conditions of both Sahih's and it has backup in other narration. For example, al-Hakim from Nishapur compiled the same hadith via al-'Ijly (a scholar who lived at the same time as abu Dawood, he died according to a-Dhhabi 294 a.H.) in his al-Mustadrak and in his report Tariq ibn Shihab clearly mentioned that the sahabi who informed him about the hadith content was abu Musa (I've marked the common narrators between Sunan abi Dawood and al-Mustadrak in bold and transliterated it to emphasize):

حدثنا أبو بكر بن إسحاق الفقيه، ثنا عبيد بن محمد العجلي، حدثني العباس بن عبد العظيم العنبري، حدثني إسحاق بن منصور، ثنا هريم بن سفيان، عن إبراهيم بن محمد بن المنتشر، عن قيس بن مسلم، عن طارق بن شهاب، عن أبي موسى، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، قال:
We were informed by abu Bakr ibn Ishaaq the faqih,  from 'Ubayd ibn Muhammad al-'Ijly, from 'Abbas ibn 'Abd al-'Addhim al-'Anbary, from Ishaaq ibn Mansur, from Huraim ibn Sufyan, from Ibraheem ibn al-Muntashir, from Qais ibn Muslim, from Tariq ibn Shihab, from Abu Musa, from the prophet Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him, who said:
" الجمعة حق واجب على كل مسلم في جماعة إلا أربعة: عبد مملوك، أو امرأة، أو صبي، أو مريض « (Source)
The Friday prayer in congregation is a necessary duty for every Muslim, with four exceptions; a slave, a woman, a boy, and a sick person.

Al-Hakim commented on this hadith (as usual in al-Mustadrak)  saying:

هذا حديث صحيح على شرط الشيخين فقد اتفقا جميعا على الاحتجاج بهريم بن سفيان ولم يخرجاه»
This hadith is sahih on the condition of both sheikhs (or teachers meaning al-Bukhari and Muslim), since both agreed on considering narratives of Huraim ibn Sufyan as evidence (authentic), but they didn't compile it.

A-Dhahahbi further confirmed the authenticity of the report in his Talkhees.
Al-Hakim further added commenting

ورواه ابن عيينة، عن إبراهيم بن محمد بن المنتشر «ولم يذكر أبا موسى في إسناده، وطارق بن شهاب ممن يعد في الصحابة
It was also narrated by ibn 'Uyaynah via Ibraheem ibn al-Muntashir, but he didn't mention in his narrator chain abu Musa. Tariq ibn Musa is counted among the sahabah.

Al-Bayhaqi who was a student of al-Hakim also compiled the hadith with a similar narrator chain on the authority of abu Musa () in his as-Sunan al-Kubra (See here in Arabic) and mentioned abu Dawood's clarification above and also the fact that the deviation came with al-'Ijly's teacher, so some of his narrators mentioned abu Musa, while other's skipped him. Al-Bayhaqi didn't report this hadith via al-Hakim from Nishapure.
See also:
Can you explain the status of mursal hadith?
How do we call a hadith which a sahabi has narrated on the authority of another sahabi?
The conclusion of an-Nawai on the hadith authenticity in al-Majmo' (see here in Arabic)
Scholarly positions on whom are dismissed from attending the Friday prayer
In different ahadith different people who are exempt from attending the prayer were mentioned out of these and with their own verification and methodology, scholars came to their verdicts, here is a full list of whom was mentioned to be dismissed from praying the Jumu'a:

boys (with scholarly consensus).
slaves (consensus, except with Dawood from the Dhahiri school of fiqh).
women (consensus, however imam a-Shafi'i held the opinion that older women should attend it),
sick people, (this in case it would cause harm to attend)
travelers (the corresponding ahadith were reported on the authority of ibn 'Umar and abu Hurraira by at-Tabarni and are regarded as weak and also in al-Bayhaqi's as-Sunan al-Kubra via al-Bukhari on the authority of Tamim a-Dari() -see here in Arabic-, see also other later narrations on the authority of other sahaba in the same book),
Bedouin (unsettled) people.

